# How to convert string from csv to hour(s):minute(s)?

Tags: python, pandas

[This link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v2HyM6NqDd6Yux-pC3xTSf-ArRSFjtxH?usp=sharing) shows my csv file and graph.

I want to represent the AVG number (which are seconds actually) as hour(s):minute(s) on y axis.

I think, it cannot be solved because I spent 3 days wit this problem.
But to be more precise, aside of lot of conversations with dateime, timedelta, timestamp nothing worked.

Either the data could no be shown on y axis because it did not represent number like variable to plot or I've got not proper representation of the data.

I was trying to create something like converting seconds to calculate with divmod
than put them on the top of the bars with annonate.

Later I have used [Timple](https://github.com/theOehrly/Timple).

I do not understand how should I create an acceptable datatype for this.

Comment: Consider including the applicable code and related diagnostic information with your question as opposed to links on other websites. Posting a well constructed question will encourage beneficial answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some related and use [`pandasDataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df["activity"] = ['run', 'swim', 'drive']
>>> df["avg"] = [86400,43200,21600]
>>> df
  activity    avg
0      run  86400
1     swim  43200
2    drive  21600
>>> df.plot.bar(x="activity")
<AxesSubplot: xlabel='activity'>
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: pandas bar plot func]

To represent time transcurred for a certain number of seconds you can use `fromtimestamp` and formatting `strftime` but it might not be compatible with matplotlib, then using **`Timple`** is something related, but graph could not be properly plotted or maybe it is needed to perform something like explore data or apply a certain statistical procedure.

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import timple
>>> tmpl = timple.Timple()
>>> tmpl.enable()
>>> timedeltas = np.array([datetime.timedelta(seconds=(s)) for s in df["avg"]])
>>> timedeltas
array([datetime.timedelta(days=1), datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=21600)], dtype=object)
>>> plt.plot(timedeltas, df["activity"])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000026FAC3F5B40>]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: plot using timple lib]

Comment: `szekond = CustomJSTickFormatter(code = '''
    let mins = Math.floor(parseInt(tick)/60);                              
    let m = mins%60 < 10 ? "0"+mins%60 : mins%60;
    let hours = Math.floor(mins/60);
    let h = hours < 10 ? "0"+hours : hours;
    return h + ":" +m;                          
''')`
This what I wanted. Sorry for format I am noob